# Apache Camel | Tracer vs Event Notifier for generating audit information

Tags: logging, apache-camel, auditing

Subsequent to my earlier question  [Apache Camel Tracer | Would log level make a difference in the amout of information logged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23216099/apache-camel-tracer-would-log-level-make-a-difference-in-the-amout-of-informat) related to Tracer, I am bit confused whether i should go for a customized tracer or a customized event notifier to generate audit information. This audit information would help us to track the state of messages within camel and provide the customer with a status report. We don't want to rely on developers putting logs in their routes for this purpose.

> Let us say that I have a route that reads a file with multiple user records. These records are read, validated, transformed and send to another system via web service. We would need to log the message (or Exchange) as it flows through each node. Then we would be able to generate status reports for customers and inform them of failure or success of each transfer and each user record. In future we also might extend this feature to send the status online to customers

Tracer is primarily a logging mechanism and also exposes MBean that can be controlled via a JMX Console. Event Notifier would 'catch' different events and then an appropriate action (logging in this case) can be taken. An advantage with Event Notifier would be that in future I can incorporate additional features like sending a email to the support team on failure.

So, question is which out of the 2 is more suitable for this type of purpose. Few deciding parameters can be:

> Performance impact (in production)
>
> Ease of maintenance
>
> Future Enhancement
>
> Management via JMX Console

Plus any other approach that can be used to implement this use case.